# Retrieve value from nested functions javascript

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I have had a look, and see some great examples of nesting functions, but even with reading them, I cannot see why I am getting *undefined* when i call this function:

```
function readBttnDetec() {
    var devid = localStorage.getItem('vBttn');
    var bd = 0;
    bd = ble.read(devid, 'fffffff0-00f7-4000-b000-000000000000',
             'FFFFFFF2-00F7-4000-B000-000000000000', 
             function(t) {
                  var data = new Uint8Array(t)
                  console.log('returns: ' + data[0]); // this returns 6
                  return data[0];
             }, function(f) {
                 console.log(f);        
             });   

             return bd;
}
```

This is the call:

```
//check button state
        var detecs = readBttnDetec();
        console.log(detecs);
        if(detecs == 2) {
            // fall detection disabled     
             $('#playfall').removeClass('km-state-active');    
        } else if(detecs == 6) {
            // fall detection enabled
            $('#playfall').addClass('km-state-active');
        } else {
            // error reading button
        }
```

I am missing something simple I am sure of it, but I cannot see it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see where you declare `ble`?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Hiya, that is declared when the App starts, and is part of a Central-BLE plugin.  It does work, I just need to connect it to a toggle switch, but i cannot return the value.  `data[0] = 6` but `bd = undefined`. Cannot work out why

Comment: @Andreas possibly a duplicate, but as I read it, this is not asyn function, nor an Ajax one.  It should not continue with the function until the button returns answer.  But perhaps i am wrong ?   But I did declare `bd` with zero, so if anything it should return Zero, not undefined ?

Comment: If you have a function with name `read` that accepts a callback, it's most likely async. Otherwise, why would you have to pass a callback in the first place?

Comment: The result you're looking for (`6`) would be the return value of an asynchronously called function - the callback of `ble.read()`. I don't know what `ble` is and what `ble.read()` returns.

Comment: Hi, I am guessing it must be async based on comments on here.  `ble.read` brings back { "0" : x }, which is a state of characteristic of a bluetooth peripheral. In my case it's either a 2, or 6. Which i wanted to change a toggle button. But  the docs I have with it did not state it was async, just 'connected to'.  But thank you for all your help, it's very much appreciated.